Matplotlib FuncAnimation Keeps Running Despite Setting frames=range(1)
I am trying to create an animation in Matplotlib where a ball moves according to constant acceleration and bounces off the walls of a square. I want for the moment the animation to display only one frame and then stop.
Here is my python code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

# Constants
SIZE = 20  # Size of the square wall
DT = 0.05  # Time step
X0,YO = 0 , 5 #Initial position in x direction , # Initial position in y direction
V0X, V0Y = 4 , 4 # Initial velocity in x direction , # Initial velocity in y direction
AX, AY = 0, 0    # Acceleration in x direction , # Acceleration in y direction
ELASTICITY = 1  # Coefficient of restitution

# Function to update the position and velocity of the ball
def update(frame):
    global x, y, vx, vy

    # Update velocity
    vx += AX * DT
    vy += AY * DT
    
    # Update position
    x += vx * DT
    y += vy * DT
    
    # Check for collisions with walls
    if np.abs(x) >= SIZE/2:
        vx = -vx * ELASTICITY
        x = np.clip(x, -SIZE/2, SIZE/2)
    if np.abs(y) >= SIZE/2:
        vy = -vy * ELASTICITY
        y = np.clip(y, -SIZE/2, SIZE/2)
        
    # Update ball position
    ball.set_data([x], [y])  # Pass coordinates as sequences
    return ball,


# Initialize position and velocity of the ball
x, y = X0, YO
vx, vy = V0X, V0Y

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(-SIZE/2, SIZE/2)
ax.set_ylim(-SIZE/2, SIZE/2)

# Create a square wall
wall = plt.Rectangle((-SIZE/2, -SIZE/2), SIZE, SIZE, edgecolor='black', facecolor='none')
ax.add_patch(wall)

# Create a ball
ball, = ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=10)

# Create an animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=1, blit=True, interval=DT*1000)


# Stop the animation after the end frame
ani.event_source.stop()

plt.show()


Problem:
Even though I set frames=1, which should theoretically display only one frame, the animation keeps running, and the ball continues to move.



it may repeat code and frames is list of information which it sends to function - and function should use this information to generate correct values. But you don't use frame in update to generate always the same values - or to use if frame == 1 to stop animation.

read documentation - you have to add repeat=False

To run animation only once you have to use repeat=False
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(..., repeat=False)

Documentation: FuncAnimation
repeat : bool, default: True

    Whether the animation repeats when the sequence of frames is completed.


And if you want to repeat the same animation but using only starting frames then you can reset data when frame == 0
def update(frame):
    global x, y, vx, vy

    if frame == 0:
        # Initialize position and velocity of the ball
        x, y = X0, YO
        vx, vy = V0X, V0Y

    # ... code ...

